# How to print items from a tkinter window onto an external file?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to transfer the content of a window onto an external file but when I do, it shows incomplete amount of items. How do I make it so that the rec_content shows everything?

Code:

```
 get_content = listbox2.get(0, END) # Get the items selected by user
            bb = Label(receipt_window, text="Bert's Burgers")
            line1 = Label(receipt_window, text='----------------------------------------------------------------')
            bb.pack()
            line1.pack()
            for con_item in get_content: # Split the item into two variables to format text
                con1, con2 = con_item.split('PHP')
                rec_content = f'{con1:<30}costs PHP{con2:<8}'
                receipt = Label(receipt_window, text=rec_content)
                receipt.pack()

 item_list = [str(rec_content), "Cost" + str(cost), "Cash Paid" + payment.get(), "Change" + str(change_formula)] 
                    with open("receipt.txt", "w") as f:
                        for line in item_list:
                            f.write(line)
                            f.write("\n")
```

Window Content:
[image: window content]

Result:
[image: Result]

Desired Result:
[image]

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: Im using python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy and convenient way to format text is to use a triple quote string.

This enables you to quickly organise or modify your receipt.

Here is a demonstration.

```py
con1 = 1
con2 = 130
con3 = 2
con4 = 100
con5 = 3
con6 = 75

cost = con2 + con4 + con6
payment = 310
change = payment - cost

receipt = f"""
                       Bert's Burgers
        {con1} pc(s) Vegan Burger     costs PHP {con2}
        {con3} pc(s) Big Fries        costs PHP {con4}
        {con5} pc(s) French Fries     costs PHP {con6}
----------------------------------------------------------------
                     Total Cost: PHP {cost}
                  Cash Tendered: PHP {payment}
                         Change: PHP {change}
"""

with open("receipt.txt", "wt") as f:
    f.write(receipt)

with open("receipt.txt", "rt") as f:
    receipt = f.read()

print(receipt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the similar issue as in your last question: You have used same variable `rec_content` in the for loop, then add this variable into `item_list` outside the for loop.  So `item_list` will have the last item in the for loop.

You need to append `rec_content` into `item_list` in the for loop:

```py
    item_list = []
    for con_item in get_content:
        con1, con2 = con_item.split('PHP')
        rec_content = f'{con1:<30}costs PHP{con2:<8}'
        receipt = Label(receipt_window, text=rec_content)
        receipt.pack()
        item_list.append(rec_content)

    item_list += [f'Cost {cost}',
                  f'Cash Paid {payment.get()}',
                  f'Change {change_formula}']

    with open('receipt.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(item_list))
```